# how to hide pdf form field with IText 7

Tags: pdf, itext, itext7, form-fields, pdf-form

I tried to hidden a form field in pdf using latest Itext 7, but could not find any solution.

I've searched the web, got example like that:

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src))
{
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create)))
    {
        AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
        form.SetFieldProperty("fieldName", "setflags", PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_HIDDEN, null);
        stamper.FormFlattening = true;
    }
}
```

It seems api is not working now.

Someone said [PdfFormField had method setVisibility()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41886714/why-dont-the-itext-7-form-field-values-print), but I also does not find it.

Comment: Your question title says "IText 7" but your code is for iText up to version 5.

Comment: @mkl yes, the code is what I found on web, and it does not work on latest Itext 7, I'm wondering how to do it